# Cannot call tests inside packages other than main

Tags: go

I am writing tests for my go code and inside sender folder, sender package I have added `exposed_api_test.go` ( also tried `exposed_api_test.go` because I have code in `exposed_api.go`)

```
package sender

import (
    "log"
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func TestTimeConsuming(t *testing.T) {

   assert.Equal(t, "test", "test1")

}
```

and when I run build and run command `go test my_project` I get `? my_project [no test files]`
When I put test out of this package ( in `main` package same test but `package main` ) and execute same command I get that test from main executed.
What is a problem and how to call tests inside other packages other than main ?

Comment: I admit I did not understand what you tried. Please show whole filesystem layout and (sample) content of the files and what you type on the command line in which folder. E.g. `go test` (no package name) works inside any package folder while running `go test full/name/of/package` requires the full import name of the package not just the name of the package declaration.

Comment: A package's tests are *for that package*; they do not magically run with anything that includes them. If you want to test package "sender" then you do `go test` in that package directory (or `go test whatever/import/path/sender`) to test that package in isolation. When you test "my_project" presumably that should only be testing package main and the integration logic, not that dependant packages are functional. (As with all the go tools, there is the `some/path/...` short-cut to select all packages at and bellow `some/path`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
go test my_project/...
```

Or if you are within your project:

```
go test ./...
```